# Eclipse graphical layout suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, user-interface

All of a sudden my graphical layout editor won't show show any elements. Everything looks just like normal, except that all views are invisible. This goes for all projects, and *almost* all controls.

So I can mark any buttons, layout etc. There's the blue square around them, but they don't render.

I have googled but can't find any solution to this. I guess someone must have had the same problem. This just suddenly started.

All my layouts are just white, and if a drop a new control, like a button, it's added in the xml, but it doesn't show.

Anyone that knows anything?

The layouts work flawless on the phone. So this is just an Eclipse-problem.

Here's an example.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerSetup_exerciseName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/timer_setup_exercise_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/views_animation" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/timerSetup_row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timerSetup_txtMaxReps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/max_reps_label"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/timerSetup_row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/exercise_table_row_height"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timerSetup_repsLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/reps_metronome_label" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/timerSetup_metronomeToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textOn="@string/on" 
            android:textOff="@string/off" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/timerSetup_row3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/timer_setup_row_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timerSetup_rpmLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rpm_min_label" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/timerSetup_rpm_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </TableRow>



</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The class starts like this (it doesn't matter if I remove isInEditMode):

```
public TimerSetupView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            _context = context;

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer_setup, this);
```

Here's how it looks in the graphical Layout (I needed to hide the title):
[image]

Comment: First thing first : Take the backup of current code in another drive.

Comment: May be problem with your ADT bundle, just try with latest one.

Comment: is there any error message below the graphical window?

Comment: @Kedarnath My code is backed up properly. I really don't have a problem with my code (or how to arrange it). Unless there is something generated in closed projects that keeps Eclipse from rendering the graphical representation of the views, which I find highly unlikely.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs No, everything looks like normal.

Comment: @RamkiAnba I have the latest SDK

Comment: have You updated eclipse, came this issue after update?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs no. I even tried downloading a fresh Eclipse ADT bundle from google, and it's the same in my projects. Some work, some don't. And I can't for the life of it understand what it is.

Comment: strange thing....sometimes there is a problem with custom views, could you make a screenshot?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I updated the post with code and graphics

Comment: Change the UI Api version

Comment: @Jimmer If it's the sdk-versions you mean I have this:     
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19". And it doesn't matter if I change it.

Comment: @Toph I mean Android rendering library version: in `UI desing panel` top right coner android logo icon: `version 4.0.3(15)`

Comment: ok. Found the problem. If I remove the anims it works. Weird. I'll look a little bit more into it and then post an answer to my own question, in case someone else has the same problem.